# Unity 3d error CS1526: A new expression requires an argument list or (), [], or {} after type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

```
List<ParticleCollisionEvent> colEvents = new List<ParticleCollisionEvent>;
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong please tell me.

Comment: you are missing () before the ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<ParticleCollisionEvent> colEvents = new List<ParticleCollisionEvent>();
```

this is a correct☻